# Deleting all files with exceptions using Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, delete-file

A simple task I'm spending way too long on.  What am I doing wrong?  I've looked at all the examples/forums etc but mine simply doesn't work.

Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/del I'd like to delete everything within dist/web/ except a subfolder within it:

```
del([
    '!dist/web/css/clubs/*.css',
     'dist/web/'
])
```

Rather than keeping `dist/web/css/clubs/*.css` the whole `dist/web/` is deleted.
Other permutations I've used are `dist/web/**` and `dist/web/**/*`. Effectively the same output.

I'm guessing that either what I'm trying to do is too complicate and unsupported or there's another way to do it that I'm missing.

Any help be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

This gets the desired result but it's not as nice as one statement.  It's also synchronous, which could be a problem to some.

```
del([
    'dist/web/**/*',
    '!dist/web/css/**'
])

del('dist/web/css/*.css');
```

Comment: It's ok for me now but it also this won't remove other folders within `dist/web/css`